# Can I change all PHP non-multibyte functions to their mb_ equivalent (i.e. mb_str_replace,mb_strlen, etc.) without breaking site?

Tags: php, unicode, multibyte

I need to upgrade a large PHP site to support UTF-8... as the first step, I want to change all the PHP code to use mb_ functions. Can I just go ahead and do that now, even though nothing else has changed to multibyte yet? (i.e. it won't break anything, right?)

I'd like to get the PHP stuff done first and have that code live and running on my existing, non-multibyte site, before I move on to the next steps (upgrading database, etc.).

Comment: Some functions support multibyte natively, so no. For instance https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mb_str_replace&scope=quickref

Comment: We can't see your code so we can't be sure. Generally it shouldn't break anything, but it all depends on what you are doing with the data. The mb functions operate on characters instead of bytes. If any of your functions were meant to operate on bytes then you might break something. This question is context specific.

Comment: It entirely depends on what your code does. It's perfectly possible to support UTF-8 without using a single `mb_*` function. Introducing these functions may or may not break anything, that entirely depends on what expectations your code has and what it does with values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom functions to obtain the result wished in addiction to other mechanisms. I suggest 5 ways:

1) a custom function that read the old strings and convert them to 8bit `get_string_utf8()`. Usage is very simple:

```
function get_string_utf8($string) {
  return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

$old_string = "Elämä on kaunis ja mahtavia yllätyksiä"; //Life is beautiful and can hold nice surprises

$new_string = get_string_utf8($old_string);
```

2) a custom function that read the old file and open it with unicode (8bit) `file_get_contents_utf8()`. Usage is very simple:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($file) {
  $content = file_get_contents($file);
  return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

$old_file = "Life_is_beautiful.html";

$new_file = file_get_contents_utf8("$old_file");
```

3) use always: `<?php ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); ?>` at begin of your php file.

4) if it's possible you should serve directly a 8bit file by saving (through php writing processes) a 8bit file (without BOM) as unicode (UTF-8)

5) use always the correct meta: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

I hope this helps.